# Javascript Validation in xsl file for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I have the below xsl:

```
    <xsl:template match="attribute[controlType='TextBox']">
    <input style="width:180pt" type="input" value="">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">fldCsXML_<xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">fldCsXML_<xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="data"/></xsl:attribute>
    </input>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to do javascript validation on the value part to not allow symbols. Just to allow numbers or letters.

Maybe with jquery similar to :

```
try bellow script this will not allow special charter # $ % ^ & * ( )

function validate() {
    var element = document.getElementById('input-field');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+/, '');
};
<input type="text" id="input-field" onkeyup="validate();"/>
```

Any help in changing the xsl above in the easiest possible way and adding jquery / javascript validation is appreciated

Comment: Try `<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z_]" />` and in JS regex add anchors `/^[a-z_]$/i.test(keyChar)`

Comment: @Tushar looking into this. Please note it needs to work for IE8 and some older browsers like Mozilla 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could do something like this:

Given input document ...

```
<t>
  <attribute>
    <controlType>TextBox</controlType>
    <name>some-name</name>
    <data>some-datum</data>
    <id>input-field</id>
    <width-on-form>180</width-on-form>
  </attribute>
</t>
```

... applying XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Some form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>        
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t">
  <form>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </form>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="attribute[controlType eq 'TextBox']">
  <input type="text" id="{id}" name="{name}" style="width:{width-on-form}pt" value="{data}" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9@]+" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

... will yield output ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Some form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form>
       <input
           type="text"
           id="input-field"
           name="some-name"
           style="width:180pt"
           value="some-datum"
           pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9@]+">
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks very good. thanks for your help but I looked up the pattern attribute and it isn't available with IE8

Comment: If so, checkout: the jQuery Tools Validator( http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/validator/index.html). You just have to link the library and add `$("#myform").validator();` where myform is the form id.