# xml datatype String don't allow symbols

Tags: xml

Is it possible to add something to the below attribute to not allow symbols in the string or to strip out the symbols before I send the xml request

```
    <attribute>
    <name>document_description</name>
    <level>Instance_BLAHOFF.BBB_BLAHOFF</level>
    <readonly>false</readonly>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <controlType>TextBox</controlType>
    <dataType>String</dataType>
    <format/>
    <description>document_description</description>
    <system>false</system>
    <data/>
    <options/>
</attribute>
```

This is what gets passed for example:

```
    <attribute>
            <name>document_description</name>
            <level>Instance_BLAHOFF.BBB_BLAHOFF</level>
            <readonly>false</readonly>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <controlType>TextBox</controlType>
            <dataType>String</dataType>
            <format></format>
            <description>document_description</description>
            <system>false</system>
            <display>true</display>
            <data>ballsss$€&amp;</data></attribute>
```

I tried to send ballsss$€& . See the way € and $ got passed but it converted & to &amp. I want to mainly eradicate all symbols e.g. € & * ( ) from being passed altogether in the easiest way possible

Comment: Define the "symbols" and specify exactly where they should not appear.  Also say whether your goal is to fail validation if said symbols appear in the wrong place or to actually remove the symbols.  (These are completely different requirements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with $ or € appearing in XML content.

However, `&` has to be written as `&amp;` in order to represent itself because `&` has special significance in XML for specifying [character and entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-references).

---

**Update**: You can certainly parse the XML and strip any characters that you wish not to be there, but it might better to attack the actual problem whereby such characters are causing your database indexing/search to go awry.  Either way, you need to look not at XML per se but to applications that process the XML.

Comment: thanks @kjhughes . yes but we have a problem. the sybols go in to the database and searching is breaking because of the symbols. I want to at least prevent these symbols from getting into the database...€  $ - £ . something like those. is there any easy fix?

Comment: I've asked a question about that yesterday here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633701/javascript-validation-in-xsl-file-for-input-field but haven't got any help really. thanks